# Renci SSH.NET - no result string returned for opmnctl

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, ssh, ssh.net

I'm trying to get result from a command through VB.NET, it is returning empty string as shown in the below code:

```
Dim connInfo As New Renci.SshNet.PasswordConnectionInfo(serverip, user, pass)
Dim sshClient As New Renci.SshNet.SshClient(connInfo)

Dim cmd As Renci.SshNet.SshCommand
Using sshClient
    sshClient.Connect()

    cmd = sshClient.RunCommand("opmnctl status -l")
    MsgBox(cmd.Result)

    sshClient.Disconnect()
End Using
```

While when I try with normal command like `"ls -ltr"` it returns the result successfully.

Is there another way of fetching result string? Or are `opmnctl` commands for OPMN Oracle engine not supported on Renci? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `opmnctl` fails for some reason, it might have produced a message on the error output.

So check also `cmd.Error` and `cmd.ExitStatus`.

---

Note that the `.RunCommand` method uses a non-interactive terminal, what may cause problems with some commands.

Particularly a different environment may be set, when the non-interactive terminal is used as a different set of startup scripts is executed and/or different branches in the scripts are taken (based on a value of a `TERM` environment variable).

In your case, it seems that the `opmnctl` is not included in `PATH` on non-interactive terminals.

You should get the same issue when you force the non-interactive terminal in your SSH client.

For example:

- With OpenSSH command-line `ssh` client, use `-T` switch (Disable pseudo-tty allocation).

  ```
  ssh -T user@host opmnctl status -l
  ```
- The same with PLink (from PuTTY package)

  ```
  plink.exe -T user@host opmnctl status -l
  ```

(The `-T` should be implicit when command is specified on command-line anyway)

---

Solution are:

- Fix your startup scripts to include the `opmnctl` to `PATH` even on non-interactive terminals (preferred)
- Use a full path to `opmnctl` in your command.
- Modify SSH.NET code to issue `SendPseudoTerminalRequest` request in `.RunCommand` implementation (I didn't test this).