# Command (.4gl) executed with SSH.NET SshClient.RunCommand fails with "No such file or directory"

Tags: c#, linux, ssh, ssh.net, 4gl

I have a web service that uses SSH.NET to call a shell script on a Unix box.

If I run the script normally, it works fine, does its work correctly on the Informix DB.

Just some background:
I call a script that executes a `.4gl` (cant show this as its business knowledge).

The g4l is giving the following error back in a log, when I execute it with SSH.NET:

> fglgo: error while loading shared libraries: libiffgisql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   file_load ended: 2017-09-21 15:37:01

C# code to execute SSH.NET script

```
sshclients = new SshClient(p, 22, username, password);
sshclients.Connect();
sshclients.KeepAliveInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
sshclients.RunCommand("sh " + Script_dir);
```

I added the `KeepAliveInterval`, to see, if it helps.

My question is the error I am getting from Unix/4gl.
Why is this happening and who can I get the script to execute correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SshClient.RunCommand` uses SSH "exec" channel internally. It, by default, (rightfully) does not allocate a pseudo terminal (PTY) for the session. As a consequence a different set of startup scripts is (might be) sourced. And/or different branches in the scripts are taken, based on absence/presence of the `TERM` environment variable. So the environment might differ from the interactive session, you use with your SSH client.

So, in your case, the `PATH` is probably set differently; and consequently the shared object cannot be found.

To verify that this is the root cause, disable the pseudo terminal allocation in your SSH client. For example in PuTTY, it's *Connection > SSH > TTY > Don't allocate a pseudo terminal*. Then, go to *Connection > SSH > Remote command* and enter your `g4l` command. Check *Session > Close window on exit > Never* and open the session. You should get the same *"No such file or directory"* error.

---

Ways to fix this, in preference order:

1. Fix the scripts not to rely on a specific environment.
2. Fix your startup scripts to set the `PATH` the same for both interactive and non-interactive sessions.
3. If the command itself relies on a specific environment setup and you cannot fix the startup scripts, you can change the environment in the command itself. Syntax for that depends on the remote system and/or the shell. In common *nix systems, this works:

   ```
    sshclients.RunCommand("PATH=\"$PATH;/path/to/g4l\" && sh ...");
   ```
4. Another (not recommended) approach is to force the pseudo terminal allocation for the "exec" channel.

   Though SSH.NET does not support this. You would have to modify its code issue `SendPseudoTerminalRequest` request in `.RunCommand` implementation (I didn't test this).

   You can also try to use "shell" channel using `.CreateShell` method. For it, SSH.NET does support pseudo terminal allocation.

   Though, using the pseudo terminal to automate a command execution can bring you nasty side effects. See for example [Is there a simple way to get rid of junk values that come when you SSH using Python's Paramiko library and fetch output from CLI of a remote machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33291631/850848)

---

For a similar issues, see

- [Renci SSH.NET - no result string returned for opmnctl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32367295/850848)
- [Certain Unix commands fail with "... not found", when executed through Java using JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40021860/850848)
- [Commands executed using JSch behaves differently than in SSH terminal (bypasses confirm prompt message of "yes/"no")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41985191/850848)
- [JSch: Is there a way to expose user environment variables to "exec" channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46349113/850848)

Answer (score 1):

Have seen similar questions asked by Informix-4gl developers as they transition to FourJs Genero and using its Web Services functionality.  The question I'll put to them is "who owns the fglgo/fglrun process that the Genero Application Server has launched, where is it running from, and what is its environment".  If needed, I'll illustrate with a simple program that does something like ...

```
MAIN 
    RUN "env > /tmp/myname.txt"
    RUN "who >> /tmp/myname.txt"
    RUN "pwd >> /tmp/myname.txt"
END MAIN
```

... and say compare with when program is running from command line.  It is normally a case like in the earlier answer of configuring so that the environment is set correctly before the 4gl program is executed.